# Using integrals to find force

Tags: definite-integrals, physics, indefinite-integrals

Let's say we have a water trough and the ends of the water trough have the shape of the region bounded by the graphs $y=x^2$ and $y=4$, with both $x$ and $y$ measured in feet. How deep would I have to fill the trough with water so that the force exerted by the water on either end of the trough is 779.423 lb? Water has a density of 62.5 pounds per cubic feet.

I know that I have to use the shape of the ends of the water trough to find the area of the end of the trough, so if I filled the trough to let's say 2 feet deep, I would solve for $\int_{0}^{2} (\sqrt x)dx$.

How would I solve this problem? Also I know that the answer is between 2 feet and 4 feet.

Comment: You're solving this incorrectly. Recall that a fluid column at the depth $w$ applies the presure $\rho g w$. Now if I fill the water up to height $h$, at height $y\le h$ I'll have pressure $\rho g (h-y)$. The total force on either end will then be $F(h) = \int_0^h \rho g (h-y) \mathrm{d}A(y)$, where $dA(y)$ is the area element at height $y$, which you can find since you know the shape of the end. Now integrate to derive an expression for $F(h)$, and then solve the equation $F(h) = 779.423$.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense, but just what does the $pg$ function signify?

Comment: $\rho$ is density, $g$ is the acc. due to gravity.

Comment: oh ok. One last question, In your first comment you said that the depth of the water was up to the height $h$. What if my $y$ is the same as my $h$, how would that work out with the integral where I subtract $y$ from $h$?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by "my $y$ is the same as my $h$". In the comment above, $y$ is just a label. It's the height you're looking at right now, and changes (and hence has nothing do do with $h$).

Comment: So looking at my scenario in my original question post, since I'm finding the pressure when the water depth is 2 feet, my $h$ is 2, correct? And then what about my $y$?

Comment: No, you need to find the *total force* on the end of the trough when it is filled to $h = 2$. Here, $y$ is a height on the trough, while $h$ is the level you've filled the trough to. At the height $y$, the pressure is $P(y) = \rho g (h-y)$, and the small force $dF = P(y) dA(y)$, and the integral is summing the forces at each depth between $0$ and $h$ (It might help to draw a figure).